# 90's Sci-Fi movie with ancient aliens and a sick kid?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I remember watching on TV part of a movie where there was a couple of parents looking for some sort of miracle alien drug to save their son who's in a coma. They wanted to get it from a humanoid alien with a deep, low pitched voice that didn't want to share it. Late into the movie he realized that his species was now extinct and it was pointless to keep the drug for himself, so he gives the bottle to the parents and lies down to die while the cave they're in crumbles.

Back to the hospital, they give that medicine to the kid. When they return, he's awake. He points at something (could have been a drawing or a window) and says something like "Look, our destination" with the same voice as the dead alien.

Sorry for the vagueness, it's been a while since I saw this and I don't remember much else. Also, I watched it in Spanish so "destination" could be "destiny" or "fate" instead.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/154603/edit) any more details. Specifically things like when you read it, or where?

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for ***Project Shadowchaser IV*** (AKA *Orion's Key* and a [whole bunch of other names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Shadowchaser_IV)) from 1996.

> After two archaeologists discover an ancient alien artifact in Africa, they must run for their lives from both the unstoppable guardian and protector that awakens as a result, and their greedy, madman employer, both of whom want the artifact.

Their son is in a coma, the alien has the cure and the movie ends exactly as you've described. Here's the trailer: